# How does ROS Topic data transfer work with large data streams?

Tags: rostopic, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am studying ROS and I have the following question. When a node wants to transfer a relatively big data stream, for example, an image, how many TCP/IP connections are created to do such a transfer. One for the whole image or one per data packet?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91451/how-does-ros-topic-data-transfer-work-with-large-data-streams?/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each topic connection will usually have a single connection which will carry many images.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0